# What is Nami referring to in this this panel?

Tags: one-piece

In chapter 852 (Possible Anime Spoilers ahead)

> when Jinbe saved Nami and Luffy from Book Worlds, Jinbe burn the book to save them. When Nami and Luffy finally escape from the book, Nami said
> *"I get the feeling... We've been this through something like this before..."*
> [image]

What is exactly Nami referring to? I can't remember she ever escaping from a or something.

Comment: someone please help make the spoiler tag, its not working :(

Comment: it was from they were captured by Mr. 3 in Little Garden arc. Zoro tried to cut off his leg and they were freed by burning and melting the candle

Comment: Spoiler tags don't like line returns for whatever reason :/

Comment: @JTR Spoiler Tags gets messed up when you try to do rely on SE to read multi line. though it'll look horrible for larger/longer stuff if you replace the new lines with `<br>` you can get it to look almost the same

Comment: @Matt i suspect it might be because it's reading multi-line spoilers as multi-line quotes with `!` at the start

Comment: @Darjeeling oh, that's right, usopp set fire to help nami, zoro, and vivi.

Comment: @Memor-X I thought it just the same like blockquote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The situation in this chapter plays out exactly as it had earlier before the time skip in the Little Garden Arc.

**Situation:** 
**A:** Nami, Zoro and Vivi are captured and stuck in an impossible situation, Mr.3 has put them in his Candle Statue. 
**B:** Luffy and Nami are captured and stuck in an impossible situation, Mont Dór has captured them in his books.

**Suggested Resolution:** Self Mutiliation 
**A:** Zoro suggests escape by cutting off his legs
**B:** Luffy tries to escape by tearing off his limbs

**Final Resolution:** Burn everything down and escape in a blaze of fire 
**A:** Usopp burns the candle stand down after Carue wraps it around with a rope.
**B:** Jinbe burns down the books freeing all the prisoners.

No wonder Nami knows this has happened before. :)

Comment: Oh, now I'm just remember about Zoro cutting off his legs!